# How to set UIProgressView progress properly?

Tags: ios

Why is there a difference between a progress of `0.2` and `0.20`? I'm really missing something here.

I have a dynamic total count of data and each data has a page.

````
let totalDataCount = 5
self.progressView.progress = Float(1/self.totalDataCount) // quotient: 0.2```
````

[image]

While if I set 0.20, I have this:

```
self.progressView.progress = 0.20
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The division 1/5 returns 0 as a result because 1 is type of Int and the result is also Int. Try to change the `1/self.totalDataCount` to `1.0/self.totalDataCount` and it will work

Comment: Wow! Just wow! Did I really have to ask this question? :D 4 years of experience and I missed this? Anyways, thanks a lot!